# Square integrable functions on $\Gamma \backslash G$ 

Tags: nt.number-theory, automorphic-forms

I am trying to understand proposition 2.1.6 in Bump's book Automorphic forms and Representations.

Let $G=GL(2,\mathbb{R})^+$ and define $G_1=G/Z^+$, where $Z^+$ denotes the center, and define $\Gamma=SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$. Let $\chi: \Gamma \to S^1$ be a group homomorphism. He writes, "Let $L^2(\Gamma\backslash G, \chi)$ be the space of measurable functions satisfying 
$$f(\gamma g u)=\chi(\gamma)f(g)\qquad \gamma\in\Gamma, u\in Z^+,g\in G$$
that are square integrable with respect to Haar measure on $G_1$."

Clearly no function which is periodic with respect to $\Gamma$ can be square integrable on $G_1$.

Can someone please explain to me what the right definition should be.

Comment: I couldn't check in the book. But it should be easy: instead of ``square integrable on $G_1$'', require ``square integrable on $\Gamma\backslash G_1$ (observe that the modulus of $f$ is left-invariant under $\Gamma$). 

Comment: $\chi$ is supposed to be the central character of $f$, so $\chi(\gamma)$ should be $\chi(u)$.

Comment: @ BR, no Bump wrote it like this.

Comment: pm, huh! You are correct. I had never seen $L^2(\Gamma\backslash G,\chi)$ used in that way before. I want to add to your second comment that since $G$ is unimodular, any quotient of $G$ by a discrete subgroup will have a unique invariant measure (since discrete groups are unimodular). And we typically ask for $\Gamma$ to be co-finite, instead of co-compact (to allow $SL_2(\mathbb Z)$ and congruence subgroups).

Comment: Oh yes, clearly $SL(2, \mathbb{Z})$ is not cofinite! I am not sure why I was talking about cocompact lattices, but unimodularity of the big group comes for free in this case. So for the OP, the invariant measure exists. Sorry for the confusion. @BR: You propbably have seen $L^2( \Gamma \backslash G, \chi)$: 1. this is an induced representation, 2. sometimes one considers Maass/modular forms $\Gamma_0(N)$ with a character of $\Gamma_0(N)$, since $L^2( \Gamma_1(N) \backslash G) \cong \bigoplus_{\chi : \Gamma_1(N) \backslash \Gamma_0(N)} L^2( \Gamma_0(N) \backslash G, \chi)$.

Comment: pm, yeah, I have seen this before, but usually written as $M_k(\Gamma,\chi)$. I just assumed it was a typo in Bump's book... Oh well! Anyway, the adelization of $\chi$ is the finite-prime part of the central character of the lift of $f$ to the adele group (see, e.g., Section 3.6 in Bump's book), so I am correct (by coincidence, not intent)! :)

Answer (score 2):

The right definition goes as follows: An element $f$ in $L^2( \Gamma \backslash G , \chi)$ is a function $f : G \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ with measurable with respect to the Haarmeasure

$$ f(\gamma z g) = \chi(\gamma) f(g),$$

and

$$ \int\limits_{\Gamma Z \backslash G} |f(g)|^2  d \mu(g) < \infty.$$

Here $\mu(g)$ is the unique (up-to-scaling) right invariant Radon measure on $\Gamma Z \backslash G$.

For the existsence and uniqueness of such measure, you can consider Theorem 1.5.2 on page 22 in Deitmar-Echterhoff "Principles on Harmonic Analysis", but this theorem should be found in any book about the analysis of locally compact groups. Actually, I think it should be in Bump as well.